# Unable to extract numbers and sum them using regex and re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I try to extract numbers from a text file with regex. Afterward, I create the sum.

Here is the code:

```
import re


def main():

    sum = 0
    numbers = []

    name = input("Enter file:")
    if len(name) < 1 : name = "sample.txt"
    handle = open(name)

    for line in handle:
        storage = line.split(" ")
        for number in storage:
            check = re.findall('([0-9]+)',number)
            if check:
                numbers.append(check)

    print(numbers)
    print(len(numbers))

    for number in numbers:
        x = ''.join(number)
        num = int(x)
        sum = sum + num

    print(sum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is, if this string `"http://www.py4e.com/code3/"`
I gets add as `[4,3]` into the list and later summed up as `43`.
Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Do you mean you need to match standalone numbers? Like with `re.findall(r'\b[0-9]+\b',number)`?

Comment: What is reason of `''.join(number)`?

Comment: Can you show us the file content as well.

Comment: Not enough information.  
You need to tell us what your expect result would be.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could solve it via the proposed solution of Than LUONG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just change `numbers.append(check)` into `numbers.extend(check)`because you want to add elements to an array. You have to use `extend()` function.

More, you do not need to use `(` `)` in your regex.

I also tried to check code on python.

```
import re

sum = 0;
strings = [
  'http://www.py4e.com/code3/',
  'http://www.py1e.com/code2/'
];
numbers = [];

for string in strings:
    check = re.findall('[0-9]+', string);
    if check:
        numbers.extend(check)

for number in numbers:
    x = ''.join(number)
    num = int(x)
    sum = sum + num

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming instead of 43 you want to get 7

The `number` variable is an array of characters. So when you use `join` it becomes  a string.

So instead of doing this you can either use a loop in to iterate through this array and covert elements of this array into `int` and then add to the `sum`.

Or

you can do this

```
import np 
number np.array(number).astype('int').tolist()
```

This makes array of character into array on integers if conversion if possible for all the elements is possible.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the string [http://www.py4e.com/code3/"](http://www.py4e.com/code3/%22) instead of calling a file which is not handled correctly in your code above fyi. The logic regex is running through two FOR loops and placing each value and it's own list[[4],[3]]. The output works when it is stepped through I think you issue is with methods of importing a file in the first statement. I replaced the file with the a string you asked about"http://www.py4e.com/code3/" you can find a running code here.

[pyregx link](https://repl.it/join/cxercdju-shaunpritchard)https://repl.it/join/cxercdju-shaunpritchard

I ran this method below calling a string with the number list and it worked fine?

````
#### Final conditional loop
   ``` for number in numbers:
        x = ''.join(number)
        num = int(x)
        sum = sum + num
    print(str(sum)) ```
````

You could also try using range or map:

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
        sum = sum + numbers
    print(str(sum))
```